# How to show an amount (in one column) that is less than the amount (by an amount) in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT A.BowlerID,
       BowlerFirstName,
       BowlerLastName,
       WonGame,
       RawScore,
       HandiCapScore
  FROM Bowlers A
 INNER JOIN Bowler_Scores B
    ON A.BowlerID = B.BowlerID
 WHERE HandiCapScore - 30 > RawScore;
```

I don't know how to show the handicap score less than 30 above the raw score?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD1NV.jpg)

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is your observed outcome and what is the expected outcome? What is wrong with your query? What is the exact condition to check? Please put more effort in your question.